# How to use constructors in php to initialize instance variables

Tags: php, oop

I know that this is a common question but the questions I've seen (about 10) confused even more than I've been.

My questions are included in the code as comments.

I have a class with three fields

```
public class Model
{
    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;
    public $prop3;

     public function _construct($params)  // doubt 1: Do I have to pass an array to a constructor, can't I pass the parameters individually
       {
                // doubt 2: How to assign the value to the instance variables
       }
}

$model = new \App\Model($whatToPuthere); //doubt 3: How to provide the constructor parameters
```

Comment: Have you read the PHP documentation about [Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)? Everything you need to know for now is explained there, with examples.

Comment: There's a documentation for everything" If we follow this line of thinking there's no reason to have stackoverflow. If I stop to read the documentation for every problem I face it will take a long long time to complete my tasks. My question is very basic concept that one  should have under his belt but in this moment I don't have the time to read the documentation.

Comment: Besides I read the documentation but I got confused by it too. Constructor in PHP is very confusing for me. You should have asked if I read the docs, before the downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proper way to do it is like :

```
public class Model
{
    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;
    public $prop3;

     public function __construct($prop1, $prop2, $prop3)  
     {
          $this->prop1 = $prop1; 
          $this->prop2 = $prop2; 
          $this->prop3 = $prop3; 
     }
}

$model = new \App\Model("prop1_value", "prop2_value", "prop3_value");
```

Comment: Please add explanation too.

Comment: Your code is invalid. Your construct method is invalid.

Comment: Still not ready to upvote... `$this->prop1 = $props1;`... are you sure `$props1` exists? :)

Comment: Look better. You are passing `$prop1` but using `$props1` while assigning.

Comment: @Spectarion you're right sir, i'm really tired i didn't see it, good catches (y)

Comment: How about reducing the visibility of instance properties to `private`, to demonstrate the concept of encapsulation here as well?

Comment: I "earned" downvotes for this question but it was worthy, solved my problem. I was missing one underline character (__construct). It's not so easy to to tell how many underlines are in row.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close, to access the current instance variables, you need to use `$this`. You also need to use 2 underscores for the construct method. Other than that, treat it as just another function.

```
class Model {

    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;
    public $prop3;

    public function __construct($prop1, $prop2, $prop3) {
        $this->prop1 = $prop1;
        $this->prop2 = $prop2;
        $this->prop3 = $prop2;
    }

}

$model = new \App\Model("prop1", "prop2", "prop3");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you to decide what is more convenient for your `\App\Model` class users. Here is an example working with fixed number of properties.

```
class Model
{
    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;
    public $prop3;

     public function __construct($prop1, $prop2, $prop3)
     {
       $this->prop1 = $prop1;
       $this->prop2 = $prop2;
       $this->prop3 = $prop3; 
     }
}

$model = new \App\Model('Property 1', 'Property 2', 'Property 3');
```

If you intend to work with dynamic number of properties, you should consider using array as parameters.

```
class Model
{
    public $prop1;
    public $prop2;
    public $prop3;

     public function __construct(array $properties)
     {
         $this->prop1 = $properties['prop1'];
         $this->prop2 = $properties['prop2'];
         $this->prop3 = $properties['prop3']; 
     }
}

$model = new \App\Model(
   array('prop1' => 'Property 1', 'prop2' => 'Property 2', 'prop3' => 'Property 3')
);
```

Comment: `public class`is not valid!